# div fixed positioning

Tags: css, html, position

[Here](http://outboxvision.com/gallery2/) is the example.

What I want is to make that thumbnails gallery remain unaffected by that top panel. 
I've tried position:absolute and fixed on the thumbnail gallery container div  and it doesn't work

Comment: You should include your code in your post so that it can stand on it's own, even if your link goes dead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you should do is add `position: absolute` to the top panel.